# A compact Lie group modulo by its maximal torus has nonzero Euler characteristic

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

In Andrew Baker's *Matrix Groups*, (in the proof of Theorem 20.11), there is an unproven statement that

> if $G$ is a compact Lie group and $T$ is a maximal torus, then $\chi
> (G/T)\ne 0$.

I have an idea that $T \rightarrow G \rightarrow G/T$ is a fibration. How then can I use the maximality of $T$ to prove that $\chi(G/T)\ne 0$? Any hint please?

Comment: I found a proof here: http://www.math.binghamton.edu/somnath/Notes/GSS1.pdf  pp. 8~10

Answer (score 4):

In fact a substantially stronger statement is true. $G/T$ is a smooth projective complex variety (called a complete [flag variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety)). It has cohomology concentrated in even degrees because it admits an "affine cell decomposition," the [Bruhat decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_decomposition), and it's known that the cohomology of such a variety is free abelian on cells, where a cell of complex dimension $k$ corresponds to a cohomology class of degree $2k$.

In fact this decomposition has exactly $|W|$ cells, where $W$ is the Weyl group of the pair $(G, T)$, and hence we in fact have

$$\chi(G/T) = |W|.$$

For example, if $G = SU(2), T = U(1)$, then $G/T \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ has a Bruhat decomposition with two cells, namely a point and $\mathbb{A}^1$, and consequently $\chi(G/T) = 2$.

I don't know how to prove your desired statement without proving at least that the cohomology is concentrated in even degrees.